# Software Keyboard Dissapears from screen when PasswordBox given focus

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a PasswordBox on a page which I am trying to set to automatically have focus when navigating to the page.

I am having problems where when I give it focus programmatically, it accepts the focus, but the keyboard goes away.

This causes a problem as the user must click off the PasswordBox, and then back on to use the control.

I have tried adding this code in the page's Loaded event, the ContentGrid.Loaded, OnNavigatedTo, and they all produce the same result.

I have tried setting the TabIndex/IsTabStop of the page, and the control itself, but it does not seem to work. The Passwordbox is the only item which has a TabIndex.

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="pwbAnswer" Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3" 
                PasswordChanged="pwbAnswer_PasswordChanged" KeyUp="pwbAnswer_KeyUp" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" />



 private void ContentGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.IsTabStop = true;
                pwbAnswer.Focus();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the Loaded Event of the PasswordBox. I had the same problem.
And than you can set the Focus to the sender, which is the PasswordBox itself, if you attached to that loading event.

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="pwbAnswer" Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3" 
                Loaded="PasswordBox_Loaded" PasswordChanged="pwbAnswer_PasswordChanged" KeyUp="pwbAnswer_KeyUp" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" />



 private void PasswordBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                PasswordBox box = sender as PasswordBox;
                box.Focus();
            }
```

or you can use the workaround with the LayoutUpdated Event.

```
<Page .... LayoutUpdated="ContentGrid_LayoutUpdated">
<PasswordBox x:Name="pwbAnswer" Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3" 
                 KeyUp="pwbAnswer_KeyUp" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" />

 private void ContentGrid_LayoutUpdated(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.IsTabStop = true;
                pwbAnswer.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I switched to using the PasswordBox's Loaded event, however the same result occurs. The keyboard is initially open for 1/10 of a second, disappears, and the box is still selected.

Comment: The LayoutUpdated worked. I missed the edited post. Thanks a lot, this worked great, and I never would have thought of that solution. Thanks!

Comment: This actually gave another problem where any control that was clicked brought up the keyboard, which didn't work for another control on the page. I fixed this by adding a handler to LostFocus, where I removed the LayoutUpdated handler. Adding the line to remove the handler directly in LayoutUpdated did not work. I ended up with 'pwbAnswer.LostFocus += (s, ee) => { this.LayoutUpdated -= Page_LayoutUpdated; };'