# Set focus to TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my WindowsPhone application I have a Text Box that needs to receive focus at a given time. What I've tried so far:

```
textBox1.Focus();
```

---

```
textBox1.UpdateLayout();
textBox1.Focus();
```

---

```
textBox1.IsTabStop = true;
textBox1.UpdateLayout();
textBox1.Focus();
```

---

```
textBox1.IsTabStop = true;
textBox1.Focus();
```

Nothing seems to work. In the Emulator, when the `Focus()` method is called, the keyboard starts to rise, but then crashes back. The TextBox has `IsTabStop` set to `true` in the properties.

Comment: I had a similar issue with .Focus(), and had to go down a different route. There was a solution that worked for me when I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045045/software-keyboard-dissapears-from-screen-when-passwordbox-given-focus

Comment: Do you have a WebBrowser on the same page? (Even if it's in a different PivotItem, if you're using Pivots)

Comment: @willmel : I'll look into that ASAP and come back with a response.

Comment: @AdrianMar - Ok. Just wondering because there's a known issue where the `WebBrowser` control automatically takes Focus away from other controls.

Comment: @keyboardP: Yes, I've read about that too, but it isn't the issue here, unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: I've used the `TextChanged` event on the TextBox, and set the `Focus()` in there. It worked for me. If anybody has another solution, please post. Thanks chaps for the ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a Silverlight bug. I've used the `TextChanged` event on the `TextBox`, and set the `Focus()` in there. Kind of an ugly workaround, but it worked for me. If anybody has another solution, please post.

Answer (score 6):

Does this help?

`this.ActiveControl = textBox1;`

Comment: This solution works in WPF not in UWP / Windows Phone.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the text box to be selected without you having to click into it (if that is what you mean by focus), try:

```
textBox1.Select();
```

Answer (score 2):

Even I have tried all the above solutions but didn't work for me. Finally I tried with the following thing, and it worked.

```
private void txtBox_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set focus property of any control at Form_Activated time..

```
private void Form_Activated(Object sender, EventArgs e){
 Textbox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: As a note, my issue was caused by a bug that was occurring in 2011. After 4 years, it might have been fixed, so this issue might not reproduce anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this by programmatically giving it focus. This can be done by
calling its Focusmethod, although this call can fail (and return false) under certain conditions.
For example, you cannot set focus on a control from a page’s constructor; it’s too early. You can,
however, call it from a page’s Loadedevent.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a textbox created in the runtime like this:

```
TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1";
```

then add this line

```
TextBox1.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox1_Loaded);
```

and then add this following event also:

```
private void TextBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late a couple years late but after playing around in windows phone 8.1 development environment I found the solution:

```
TextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

You need to pass in the type of FocusState through the FocusState class.

Comment: I can't believe 5 years ago I was writing Windows Phone applications and now this OS is approaching its final days.

Comment: Indeed I actually enjoy writing apps on this OS it's way easier than developing on android native. I guess most devs don't want to port their applications to the platform... I'll continue to develop for the platform till it's final day.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me
this.YourTextbox.TabIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

if we have tow textboxes 
exp:

```
txtPrincipal

txtPrincipal_Contact
```

if want move from `txtPrincipal` to `txtPrincipal_Contact` 
we need to write second textbox name with focus function in leave event of the current textbox exp:

[image]

```
private void txtPrincipal_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPrincipal_Contact.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spend hours in debugging, I found the [solution](http://thewindev.net/fix-keyboard-not-showing-uwp-textbox/)

```
await Task.Delay(100);
tbInput.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```